# CSS File and Images Not Appearing in Production on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently changed the entire look and feel of my website, removing all of the old images and styling and replacing it with new stuff.

However, none of the new images or styling are appearing in production even though it all is working in development.

When I look at the public files, it still has all of the old imagery and icons (I didn't want to delete anything and risk making things worse).

I've researched this ad nauseum, run asset precompile, and know there is a relatively simple solution but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: do not you need to host images in aws s3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

as of from [this reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally), you can precompile the assets in your local terminal before push to heroku,

open your terminal, and make sure you already inside the working rails folder, and run this command below

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

after you run this commnd you can push to heroku